# Android google map api not working

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, dictionary

I'm having trouble with GoogleMaps in my Android Application.

My app crashes when I use my `GoogleMap()` class and I don't realize why this is happening.
Would be great if you could help me solving this issue, since I'm two days trying to solve this and I can't.

Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mymaptest.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mytest.myapptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyBS7YGau85XafkSWUGipDnT...." />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my xml Layout file `mapview.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally my java class `GoogleMap()` :

```
public class GoogleMap extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, null, false);


        return v;
    }
}
```

This Fragment is inside an pageindicator and I want the user to slide from one fragment to the other, and this being a map. Could you please help me?

EDITED SECOND LOGCAT:

```
 com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    03-04 13:23:47.233: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    03-04 13:23:47.233: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    03-04 13:23:47.233: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    03-04 13:23:47.233: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-04 13:24:00.044: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:00.044: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.464: D/AndroidRuntime(2176): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    03-04 13:24:04.464: D/AndroidRuntime(2176): CheckJNI is ON
    03-04 13:24:04.464: D/dalvikvm(2176): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    03-04 13:24:04.474: D/dalvikvm(2176): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    03-04 13:24:04.474: D/dalvikvm(2176): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    03-04 13:24:04.474: D/dalvikvm(2176): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    03-04 13:24:04.514: D/AndroidRuntime(2176): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    03-04 13:24:04.514: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.514: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.514: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.514: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.514: W/ActivityManager(1177): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/OutspinAlpha.apk
    03-04 13:24:04.544: W/ActivityManager(1177): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/OutspinAlpha.apk
    03-04 13:24:04.544: I/PackageManager(1177): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl745987975
    03-04 13:24:04.574: D/dalvikvm(1177): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2054K, 51% free 7946K/16088K, paused 9ms, total 13ms
    03-04 13:24:04.594: D/dalvikvm(1177): GC_CONCURRENT freed 42K, 51% free 7904K/16088K, paused 7ms+9ms, total 17ms
    03-04 13:24:04.624: D/dalvikvm(1177): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1282K, 51% free 7893K/16088K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 11ms
    03-04 13:24:04.664: I/PackageManager(1177): Removing non-system package:com.codevelop.outspinalpha
    03-04 13:24:04.664: I/ActivityManager(1177): Force stopping package com.codevelop.outspinalpha appid=10053 user=-1
    03-04 13:24:04.674: I/PackageManager(1177): Package com.codevelop.outspinalpha codePath changed from /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-2.apk to /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
    03-04 13:24:04.674: I/PackageManager(1177): Linking native library dir for /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-1.apk
    03-04 13:24:04.674: I/PackageManager(1177): Running dexopt on: com.codevelop.outspinalpha
    03-04 13:24:04.914: D/dalvikvm(2201): DexOpt: load 19ms, verify+opt 143ms, 1923972 bytes
    03-04 13:24:04.934: I/ActivityManager(1177): Force stopping package com.codevelop.outspinalpha appid=10053 user=-1
    03-04 13:24:04.934: W/PackageManager(1177): Code path for pkg : com.codevelop.outspinalpha changing from /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-2.apk to /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-1.apk
    03-04 13:24:04.934: W/PackageManager(1177): Resource path for pkg : com.codevelop.outspinalpha changing from /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-2.apk to /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-1.apk
    03-04 13:24:04.944: D/PackageManager(1177): New package installed in /data/app/com.codevelop.outspinalpha-1.apk
    03-04 13:24:04.944: W/PackageManager(1177): Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES in package com.codevelop.outspinalpha
    03-04 13:24:04.954: I/ActivityManager(1177): Force stopping package com.codevelop.outspinalpha appid=10053 user=0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1325): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1325): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1304): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1304): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.954: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.964: D/dalvikvm(1364): GC_EXPLICIT freed 360K, 32% free 5327K/7756K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 5ms
    03-04 13:24:04.964: W/Trace(1273): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.964: W/Trace(1273): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.974: D/dalvikvm(1273): GC_EXPLICIT freed 184K, 13% free 2663K/3048K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 4ms
    03-04 13:24:04.974: W/Trace(1717): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.974: W/Trace(1717): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1689): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/ApplicationContext(1689): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1689): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: I/InputReader(1177): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:04.994: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/InputMethodManagerService(1177): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: D/PackageManager(1177): generateServicesMap() for 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.004: D/PackageManager(1177): generateServicesMap() for 0
    03-04 13:24:05.054: W/Trace(1689): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.054: W/Trace(1689): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.074: D/dalvikvm(1177): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1240K, 51% free 7919K/16088K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 13ms
    03-04 13:24:05.074: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.074: I/InputReader(1177): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    03-04 13:24:05.074: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.074: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: E/Trace(2220): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.484: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.514: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.514: W/Trace(1364): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.514: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: D/dalvikvm(2220): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3093K/3288K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
    03-04 13:24:05.524: D/dalvikvm(2220): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3093K/3288K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 3ms
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1177): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.524: W/Trace(1243): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.584: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.584: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.584: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.604: D/dalvikvm(2220): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 5% free 3216K/3364K, paused 8ms, total 9ms
    03-04 13:24:05.604: I/dalvikvm-heap(2220): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.944MB for 728532-byte allocation
    03-04 13:24:05.614: D/dalvikvm(2220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 4% free 3924K/4076K, paused 9ms+0ms, total 11ms
    03-04 13:24:05.624: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.624: W/Trace(2220): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:05.624: D/AndroidRuntime(2220): Shutting down VM
    03-04 13:24:05.624: W/dalvikvm(2220): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4cba908)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.ex(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.a(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.codevelop.outspinalpha.MapLocation.onCreateView(MapLocation.java:27)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:433)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.setCurrentItem(TabPageIndicator.java:243)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.onMeasure(TabPageIndicator.java:116)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    03-04 13:24:05.624: E/AndroidRuntime(2220):     at java.lang.reflect.M
    03-04 13:24:05.657: W/ActivityManager(1177):   Force finishing activity com.codevelop.outspinalpha/.MainBrowse
    03-04 13:24:05.657: W/WindowManager(1177): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 22015
    03-04 13:24:14.555: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:14.555: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:14.555: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:14.555: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:14.555: W/Trace(1645): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:32.244: D/ExchangeService(1557): Received deviceId from Email app: null
    03-04 13:24:32.244: D/ExchangeService(1557): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: D/ExchangeService(1557): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: D/ExchangeService(1557): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: D/ExchangeService(1557): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/ActivityManager(1177): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
    03-04 13:24:37.254: D/ExchangeService(1557): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: W/Trace(1557): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b4f10120 that was originally bound here
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b4f10120 that was originally bound here
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/ActivityThread(1557):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557): null
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b4f10120 that was originally bound here
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    03-04 13:24:37.254: E/StrictMode(1557):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    03-04 13:24:37.264: W/ActivityManager(1177): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@b51f43e8
    03-04 13:24:37.264: W/ActivityManager(1177): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
    03-04 13:24:45.376: W/Trace(1352): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    03-04 13:24:45.376: W/Trace(1352): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: Where is your logcat error ?

Comment: Can you provide logcat please?

Comment: yes, its on the edit. Thanks!

Comment: please Restarting the Eclipse IDE and try again

Comment: The thing which you have posted is not logcat error.

Comment: I did it, didn't work. I think its about something wrong with the app. Is the manifest or even the code right? I pasted it from the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map , just inflated the fragment to catch the xml file, but it seems ok to me

Comment: I'm two days around this issue to implement google maps

Comment: this error is not code error or like that, create a new work-space. Import your projects maybe this worked

Comment: Now I put the real Logcat, sorry I was confused

Comment: Well, even Google Maps demos and samples aren't working..

Comment: see http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=138637

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place a map inside of a fragment then I suggest you to use the `MapView` object in your layout instead of the `SupportMapFragment`, here is a code that works for me:

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the fragment itself:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment  {

private static final String TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private MapView mapView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_mapview, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    mapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Well it states that:

```
A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Are you sure you have it in the manifest file as you have posted in your question?

Comment: And what does the logcat states?

Comment: put that on my second edit. (even google's sample apps dont work either on emulator or my mobile)

Comment: yes, it's there as you can see on my the manifest file. This is very strange

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have added latest version of google play services to your project build path

Then, make following changes to your GoogleMap class

```
public class GoogleMap extends Fragment {

    MapView m;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
        m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return v;
    }
```

Use the following code in your manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map" />
```

Make sure you change the name of your activity as it contradicts with the name of GoogleMap class provided by google play services.

Comment: Didn't work because I need to use fragment since its under a pagerindicator of fragments, is there any way I can change for it to work on a simple Fragment?

Comment: add this line before return v in your GoogleMap class

Comment: MapView m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

Comment: R.id.mapview .. here mapview is your fragment id in your manifest file

Comment: in your case it will be R.id.map

Comment: copied everything from [this link](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=138637). if you copy one text you need put link of that site too